# Nuxt 3 plugin throws error when accessing private config

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a simple plugin that needs access to some API credentials so that data can be fetched in pages. I am assuming that given these credentials are private, they should **not** be in the public config:

```json
runtimeConfig: {
    contentful: {
        environment: '',
        spaceId: '',
        accessToken: ''
    },
},
```

And in my plugin which I then use to initialise an API client:

```js
import { createClient } from "contentful";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {

  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()

  const client = createClient({
    space: runtimeConfig.contentful.spaceId,
    accessToken: runtimeConfig.contentful.accessToken,
    environment: runtimeConfig.contentful.environment
  })

  console.log(runtimeConfig.contentful)

  return {
    provide: {
      contentful: client
    }
  }
})
```

The vars are available on SSR (the `console` line shows that) but then I get this error in the browser:

```
Expected parameter space

at createClient (http://localhost:63921/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/contentful.js?v=18c196e8:5296:11)
at http://localhost:63921/_nuxt/plugins/example.js:10:18
at fn (http://localhost:63921/_nuxt/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/nuxt.mjs?v=18c196e8:146:27)
...
```

If I instead use public runtime, it works fine. I had assumed that this was not safe given that I don't want to expose the API access token. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: And what that 500 error says?

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')`

Comment: You can edit your question and paste error.

Comment: If you need them on client, it has to be public. Sometimes you don't have other choice.

Comment: @Mises I've updated the question which should hopefully now be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins without `.server` or `.client` suffix are global and work on server and client. If you want to use secrets in API on server side, add to your plugin `example.server.ts` suffix.

Comment: @RussBack All you were need to do is to paste error with details.